# When writing and preparing a campaign should I include all the side stories and all possible encounters?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, campaign-development, gm-preparation

I have worked out an entire world with a story and several side stories (they'll be optional) should I just put them in the middle of the story of where they'd be available or should I put them into a separate area for them and just put a note to where to find the details of the quest when they'd be important?